# Определить размер папок

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, командная-строка

Как в командной строке `linux` (`PuTTY`) определить занимаемое место (вывести в `gb`) каждой папки и файла (без рекурсивной вложенности) для текущей дериктории (в которой сейчас находимся)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отображает размер и имена файлов и директорий, с соритровкой по размеру

```
du -sk * | sort -rn
```

плюс см. [команды Linux для работы с VPS/VDS серверами](http://coderhs.com/snippets/vps-vds-linux-commands)

Покажет все файлы в мегабайтах и отсортирует от большего к меньшему.

```
du -sm *| sort -nr
```

Отсортировать файлы от большего к меньшему и прописать размеры в мегабайтах и килобайтах

```
du -s *|sort -nr|cut -f 2-|while read a;do du -hs $a;done
```

Comment: Спасибо. Можно ли как-то вывести размер в `mb`/`gb`?

Comment: Пожалуйста) Добавил.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз.